# Displaying multiple columns on LookupEdit of Devexpress

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I have a `DataSource` bound to a `LookUpEdit`. For example I have 2 columns `FirstName` and `LastName` and I want to set `DisplayMember` property to these two columns.
I found that I should subscribe to `lookUp_CustomDisplayText()` and edit display text property like this:

```
private void lookUpCompanyPerson_CustomDisplayText(object sender, CustomDisplayTextEventArgs e)
{
     LookUpEdit edit = sender as LookUpEdit;

     if (e.DisplayText != "")
     {
           e.DisplayText = e.DisplayText + " " + (string)e.Value;          
     }            
}
```

but I did not understand what `e.Value` is and I want to display another column for selected row, not the valuemember of selected row.

This is how I bind the datasource to lookupedit:

```
 private void populateComboBoxForCompanyPerson()
 {
     lookUpCompanyPerson.Properties.ForceInitialize();
     bs = new BindingSource(myDataSet, "CompanyPerson");            
     lookUpCompanyPerson.Properties.DataSource = bs;
     lookUpCompanyPerson.Properties.DisplayMember = "CompanyName";
     lookUpCompanyPerson.Properties.ValueMember = "PersonID";
     this.lookUpCompanyPerson.Properties.Columns.Add(new LookUpColumnInfo("PersonID"));
     this.lookUpCompanyPerson.Properties.Columns["PersonID"].Visible = false;            
     this.lookUpCompanyPerson.Properties.Columns.Add(new LookUpColumnInfo("FirstName"));
     this.lookUpCompanyPerson.Properties.Columns.Add(new LookUpColumnInfo("LastName"));
     this.lookUpCompanyPerson.Properties.Columns.Add(new LookUpColumnInfo("CompanyName"));                
 }
```

And this is what my datasource looks like: [image: datasource]

Comment: You should probably post the full method. This is an event handler right?

Comment: Ok thanks - I think to go further I'd need to see what your data source is like and how it is being bound to the LookUpEdit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the DevExpress documentation:

- `e.Value` gets or sets editor's current value.
- `e.DisplayText` gets or sets an editor's display text

> The lookup editor's value is obtained from the data source field specified by the RepositoryItemLookUpEditBase.ValueMember property. The GetDataSourceRowByKeyValue method searches for the specified value within this field and returns an object representing the first found record.
>
> The GetDataSourceRowByKeyValue method's return value depends upon the type of the underlying data source. If the data source is a System.Data.DataTable or a System.Data.DataView, this method returns a System.Data.DataRowView object. If the data source is a custom list of items, the appropriate list item is returned.

You want to set the `e.Value` to the value that you want to display in the control.

```
private void lookUpCompanyPerson_CustomDisplayText(object sender, CustomDisplayTextEventArgs e)
{
    RepositoryItemLookUpEdit props
    if (sender is LookUpEdit)
        props = (sender as LookUpEdit).Properties;
    else
        props = sender as RepositoryItemLookUpEdit;
    if (props != null && (e.Value is int))
    {
        object row = props.GetDataSourceRowByKeyValue(e.Value);
        if (row != null)
        {
            e.Value = String.Format("{0} {1}", (DataRowView)row["FirstName"], (DataRowView)row["LastName"]);
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, here are some useful pages with more documentation:

- [BaseEdit.CustomDisplayText Event](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraEditorsBaseEdit_CustomDisplayTexttopic)
- [RepositoryItemLookUpEdit.GetDataSourceRowByKeyValue Method](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItemLookUpEdit_GetDataSourceRowByKeyValuetopic)

Comment: Error 1: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object' on row["FirstName] and row["LastName"]

Comment: What is the type of myDataSet? If it's System.Data.DataTable or a System.Data.DataView you can use the edited code above which casts the object as a DataRowView.

Comment: `public partial class myDataSet: global::System.Data.DataSet`

Answer (score 4):

I've changed Ian O'Brien's code a little bit and it works:

```
private void lookUpCompanyPerson_CustomDisplayText(object sender, CustomDisplayTextEventArgs e)
{
      RepositoryItemLookUpEdit props;
      if (sender is LookUpEdit)
      props = (sender as LookUpEdit).Properties;
      else
      props = sender as RepositoryItemLookUpEdit;

      if (props != null && (e.Value is int))
      {
          DataRowView row = props.GetDataSourceRowByKeyValue(e.Value) as DataRowView;

          if (row != null)
          {
              e.DisplayText = String.Format("{0} {1}", row["FirstName"], row["LastName"]);

          }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i have use it, just like this;

```
cmb_tip.Properties.DataSource = _dt;
cmb_tip.Properties.ValueMember = "Value";
cmb_tip.Properties.DisplayMember = "Type";
cmb_tip.Properties.PopulateColumns();
cmb_tip.Properties.Columns["Value"].Visible = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how it works with LookupEditControl in Version 15.2.7 and a Class:

```
private void lookUpEditPatients_CustomDisplayText(object sender, DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.CustomDisplayTextEventArgs e)
    {
        var edit = sender as LookUpEdit;
        var props = edit.Properties;
        var pat = (Patients4ComboBoxVm) props?.GetDataSourceRowByKeyValue(e.Value);
        if (pat != null)
        {
            e.DisplayText = pat.Nachname + ", " + pat.Vorname + "; " + pat.Geburtsdatum + "; " + pat.Versicherungsnummer;
        }
    }
```